# PHP Array in Array in Array to Foreach and String [Multiple in array]

Tags: php, arrays, string, loops, foreach

I tried to do it, but my php knowledge is minimal. I hope you can help with this.  The foreach loop I want to do;

```php
Array
(
    [istasyonBilgileriList] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [istasyonId] => 234515950
            [istasyonKodu] => 1401
            [istasyonAdi] => Ankara
            [enlem] => 0.000000000000
            [boylam] => 0.000000000000
            [tarih] => Jul 25, 2017 10:00:00 AM
        )

        [1] => Array
        (
            [istasyonId] => 234515951
            [istasyonKodu] => 1402
            [istasyonAdi] => Enveriye
            [enlem] => 0.000000000000
            [boylam] => 0.000000000000
            [tarih] => Jul 25, 2017 10:00:00 AM
        )
        ...
        ...
        ...
    )
)
```

The example I want to make is the foreach loop

```php
foreachETC {
    $istasyonId   = $value['istasyonId'];
    $istasyonKodu = $value['istasyonKodu'];
}
```

Comment: What have you actually tried? The syntax you have is invalid

Comment: If you use var_export to dump your array, and then copy that into your question, it's easier for us to use. 
 `var_export($your_array);`.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar example, to output the inner foo values, we can loop through the *boz* key:

```
<?php

$data =
[
    'boz' => 
    [
        [
            'foo' => 'Food'
        ],
        [
            'foo' => 'Fool'
        ]
    ]
];

foreach($data['boz'] as $item) {
    echo $item['foo'] . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Food
Fool
```